# My program doesn't seem to follow through my If statements

Tags: c#

```
        //Declarations 
        double height;
        double weight;
        double BMI;
        int Const;


        //Reading User Input

        //HEIGHT
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the person's height in inches: ");
            height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                if (height < 5 && height > 120)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The height entered must be between 5” and 120” inclusive.");

        }
            //MASS
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the person's weight in lbs: ");
            weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                if (weight < 0.5 && weight > 999)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine("The weight entered must be between 0.5 lb. and 999 lb. inclusive.");
                }

            //BMI Calculations
            Const = 703;
            BMI = (weight / (height * height)) * Const;


            //Category Assignments
            if (BMI <= 16)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The BMI for a " + height + "tall person who weighs " + weight + " lb. is 26.7, which is categorized as 'serverly underwieght'.");
            }
            else if (BMI > 16 && BMI <= 18.5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The BMI for a " + height + "tall person who weighs " + weight + " lb. is 26.7, which is categorized as 'underwieght'.");
            }
            else if (BMI > 18.5 && BMI <= 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The BMI for a " + height + "tall person who weighs " + weight + " lb. is 26.7, which is categorized as 'healthy'.");
            }
            else if (BMI > 25 && BMI < -30)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The BMI for a " + height + "tall person who weighs " + weight + " lb. is 26.7, which is categorized as 'Overweight'.");
            }
            else if (BMI > 30)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The BMI for a " + height + "tall person who weighs " + weight + " lb. is 26.7, which is categorized as 'Obese'.");
            }



        }

    }
}
```

First question on here, so sorry about not making proper format. Anyways, my program just closes after I enter in the weight, like instantly. Its a console application btw.

Also, if I enter a weight or height that is below or above the requirements, it doesn't display the error message, just goes on then closes.

Comment: This is an excellent time to learn to use your debugger.  It will allow you to step through one line at a time and see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking between a range 5 and 120 it should be  as follows, because `height < 5 && height > 120` will return false.

```
if (height > 5 && height < 120)
  {
   Console.WriteLine("The height entered must be between 5” and 120” inclusive.");
  }
```

Similarly for weight,

```
if (weight > 0.5 && weight < 999)
 {
  Console.WriteLine("The weight entered must be between 0.5 lb. and 999 lb. inclusive.");
 }
```

if you want to see the output in console, Add this at the end of the program

```
Console.ReadLine()
```

which will wait until the user press some key

Answer (score 0):

Add `Console.ReadLine` at the end of your programm and it will stay open.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional Console.ReadLine or Console.ReadKey at the end. This will force the console app to wait for the user to type enter or any other key before exiting.